# I have segmented image into 16*16 blocks. Now i want to convert each block into images

Tags: matlab

I have an image divided into 16x16 blocks, where each block are like an array. How can I convert each block as an image?

My code is:

```
I=imread(image);
img=rgb2gray(I);    
[col, row] = find(img<250);    
imout = I(min(col):max(col), min(row):max(row));  
imshow(imout);
[rows columns numberOfBands]=size(imout);
blockSizeR = 16;
blockSizeC = 16;
wholeBlockRows = floor(rows / blockSizeR);
wholeBlockCols = floor(columns / blockSizeC);
blockNumber=1;
for row = 1 : blockSizeR : rows
  for col = 1 : blockSizeC : columns
    row1 = row;
    row2 = row1 + blockSizeR - 1;
    row2 = min(rows, row2);
    col1 = col;
    col2 = col1 + blockSizeC - 1;
    col2 = min(columns, col2);
    block=imout(row1:row2, col1:col2);
    subplot(16,16,blockNumber);
    imshow(block);
    blockNumber = blockNumber + 1;
  end    
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to image"? Do you want to save the images e.g. as .jpg?

Answer (score 0):

To create an image file with an array, you should use the built-in `imwrite` function.

Here is a piece of code that does pretty much the same as what you already do, plus saving it into files:

```
% ...
% imout contains the image to split

n = 16;

% Divide into nxn images
s1 = [n*ones(1,floor(size(imout,1)/n)) mod(size(imout,1),n)];
s2 = [n*ones(1,floor(size(imout,2)/n)) mod(size(imout,2),n)];
C = mat2cell(imout, s1, s2);

% Save into files
outpref = '/your/path/img_';
outsuff = '.png';
[I, J] = meshgrid(1:numel(s1), 1:numel(s2));
cellfun(@(x,i,j) imwrite(x, [outpref num2str(i) '_' num2str(j) outsuff]), C, num2cell(I'), num2cell(J'));
```

Comment: If this anwers to your question, please mark it as solved such that the community knows you no longer need help on this topic. Best,